# How to get bundle for a struct?

Tags: swift, struct, nsbundle

In Swift, you can call

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

in any class and get the current bundle. If you `NSBundle.mainBundle()` this will fail getting correct bundle when for example running unit tests.

So how can you get the current bundle for a Swift `struct`?

Comment: Also searching for an answer to this.. I currently have a placeholder class definition and an `NSBundle` extension helping out so I can continue working until a proper solution is found

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The best solution here depends on what you need a bundle for.

Is it to look up resources that exist only in a specific app, framework, or extension bundle that's known to be loaded when the code you're writing runs? In that case you might want to use [`init(identifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithIdentifier:) instead of dynamically looking up the bundle that defines a certain type.

Beware of "follows the type" bundle lookups. For example, if a framework class `Foo` uses `NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)` to load a resource, a subclass of `Foo` defined by the app loading that framework will end up looking in the app bundle instead of the framework bundle.

If you do need a "follows the type" bundle lookup for a struct (or enum), one workaround that might prove helpful is to define a class as a subtype:

```
struct Foo {
     class Bar {}
     static var fooBundle: NSBundle { return NSBundle(forClass: Foo.Bar.self) }
}
```

Note there's nothing dynamic here, because nothing needs to be — every `Foo` comes from the same type definition (because structs can't inherit), so its static type matches its dynamic type.

(Admittedly, an `NSBundle(forType:)` that could handle structs, enums, and protocols might make a [nice feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com). Though I imagine it could be tricky to make it handle extensions and everything...)

Comment: would "static let fooBundle = Bundle(for: Foo.Bar.self)" work too? @rickster

Comment: Yeah, that looks workable. (My original answer predates `NSBundle` getting renamed to `Bundle` for Swift.) Feel free to test it, though.

Answer (score 23):

```
extension Bundle {
    static var current: Bundle {
        class __ { }
        return Bundle(for: __.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works on Xcode 11.7 + SwiftUI on Live Preview

Answer (score 11):

Updated for Swift 3.0+:

```
struct Foo {
     class Bar {}
     static var fooBundle: Bundle { return Bundle(for: Foo.Bar.self) }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5

```
struct Foo {
    class Bar {}
    static var fooBundle: Bundle { return Bundle(for: Foo.Bar.self) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift Packages, we get the Bundle where the Swift struct is declared anywhere in the same module (target) via:

```
Bundle.module
```

However, we need to import a resource in the Package to get this autogenerated.

`Bundle.main` also works for other projects if you don't have extension targets.

Comment: What do you mean by import a resource in the Package to get this autogenerated?

How do you get this working?

Comment: Resources include storyboard files, asset catalogs, Core Data .xcdatamodeld files and localised resources. For more info, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundling-resources-with-a-swift-package. In order to access `Bundle.module` we need to add one of these resource files to the package.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4+**

You can do `let bundle = InternalConstants.bundle` if you add this struct to your project. A very elegant solution in my opinion.

```
internal struct InternalConstants {
    private class EmptyClass {}
    static let bundle = Bundle(for: InternalConstants.EmptyClass.self)
}
```

Another potential solution (less elegant):

```
internal struct InternalConstants {
    internal static let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.hello.world")!
}
```